# I want a query which will do word splitting by space

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Example :
The last name is 'Daniel Thomas Kon'
Output is expecting based on this condition - > if less than or equal to 3  put 1st word in last name and remaining will be in firstname

Here the output will be--

| last name | first name |
| --- | --- |
| Daniel | Thomas Kon |

Here the output will be--

| last name | first name |
| --- | --- |
| Daniel | Thomas Kon |

Comment: "if less than or equal to 3" - if *what* is less than 3; characters, or words, or something else? What if that is more than 3? It might be helpful to show more sample data and expected results, and also what you have tried - have you looked at the `instr` and `substr` functions?

Comment: does your version support regex ?

Comment: @AlexPoole its word , if its more than 3 then first name would hold 2 words and last name will hold 2 words

Comment: @trillion yes its support

Comment: @Nidhi more than or less than 3 , that is the total length of the name ?

Comment: @trillion  i am  calculating 3 based on word

Comment: what do you mean by this : if its more than 3 then first name would hold 2 words and last name will hold 2 words

Comment: @Nidhi what if the length is 5 ? or 6 or 7

Answer (score 0):

If you want the last one-or-two words as first names and the preceding words as last names then you can use a mix of greedy and non-greedy qualifiers in a regular expression:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(name, '^(\S+(\s+\S+)*?)\s+(\S+(\s+\S+)?)$', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS last_names,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(name, '^(\S+(\s+\S+)*?)\s+(\S+(\s+\S+)?)$', 1, 1, NULL, 3) AS first_names
FROM   table_name
```

or, without regular expressions (which is more to type but will be faster):

```sql
SELECT CASE
       WHEN sep1 = 0      THEN name
       WHEN sep_last2 = 0 THEN SUBSTR(name, 1, sep1 - 1)
       ELSE                    SUBSTR(name, 1, sep_last2 - 1)
       END AS last_names,
       CASE
       WHEN sep1 = 0      THEN NULL
       WHEN sep_last2 = 0 THEN SUBSTR(name, sep1 + 1)
       ELSE                    SUBSTR(name, sep_last2 + 1)
       END AS first_names
FROM   (
  SELECT name,
         INSTR(name, ' ', 1, 1) AS sep1,
         INSTR(name, ' ', -1, 2) AS sep_last2
  FROM   table_name
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (name) AS
  SELECT 'Daniel Thomas Kon'             FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Abbot Alice'                   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Baron Betty Beryl Becky'       FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Count Carol Chloe Clara Carly' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

| LAST_NAMES | FIRST_NAMES |
| --- | --- |
| Daniel | Thomas Kon |
| Abbot | Alice |
| Baron Betty | Beryl Becky |
| Count Carol Chloe | Clara Carly |

---

If you want to have at most 2 last-names then:

```sql
SELECT CASE
       WHEN sep1 = 0 THEN name
       WHEN sep3 = 0 THEN SUBSTR(name, 1, sep1 - 1)
       ELSE               SUBSTR(name, 1, sep2 - 1)
       END AS last_names,
       CASE
       WHEN sep1 = 0 THEN NULL
       WHEN sep3 = 0 THEN SUBSTR(name, sep1 + 1)
       ELSE               SUBSTR(name, sep2 + 1)
       END AS first_names
FROM   (
  SELECT name,
         INSTR(name, ' ', 1, 1) AS sep1,
         INSTR(name, ' ', 1, 2) AS sep2,
         INSTR(name, ' ', 1, 3) AS sep3
  FROM   table_name
)
```

Which outputs:

| LAST_NAMES | FIRST_NAMES |
| --- | --- |
| Daniel | Thomas Kon |
| Abbot | Alice |
| Baron Betty | Beryl Becky |
| Count Carol | Chloe Clara Carly |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/e7a0Zm1X)

Answer (score -1):

Please check below

```
DECLARE @Table VARCHAR(100) = 'Daniel Thomas Kon'
DECLARE @PartialString VARCHAR(100) = SUBSTRING(@Table, CHARINDEX(' ', @Table) + 1, len(@Table))

SELECT CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(@Table, CHARINDEX(' ', @Table) + 1, len(@Table))) + 1
    ,CASE 
        WHEN (len(@Table) - len(replace(@Table, ' ', '')) + 1) = 3
            THEN SUBSTRING(@Table, CHARINDEX(' ', @Table) + 1, len(@Table))
        WHEN (len(@Table) - len(replace(@Table, ' ', '')) + 1) > 3
            THEN SUBSTRING(@PartialString, CHARINDEX(' ', @PartialString) + 1, len(@PartialString))
        END AS firstname
    ,CASE 
        WHEN (len(@Table) - len(replace(@Table, ' ', '')) + 1) = 3
            THEN SUBSTRING(@Table, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', @Table) + 1)
        WHEN (len(@Table) - len(replace(@Table, ' ', '')) + 1) > 3
            THEN SUBSTRING(@Table, 0, len(@PartialString) - 1)
        END AS lastname
```

Please check on below link

https://dbfiddle.uk/BJbHD8J0

Comment: The question is tagged Oracle; this is not valid SQL in Oracle's dialect.

Comment: this is also tagged with sql also

Comment: Please read the tag description for SQL - it does **NOT** mean SQL Server it means that the OP is looking for an SQL query of a dialect indicated by the other tags (and if there are no other tags then they are looking for SQL that matches the ANSI/ISO standard).